# How do I add leading zeroes to int used in Text that is gathered from Firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I currently have an issue with single-digit times showing as single digits, i.e. 9:05 am showing as 9:5.

The time is recovered from Firebase where they also appear as single digits.

The Time Selector code is:

```
var timeInput = const TimeOfDay(hour: 00, minute: 00);
        
...
        
'timeHour': timeInput.hour,
  

'timeMinute': timeInput.minute,
    
 ...
    
    
void 

_selectTime() async {
    final TimeOfDay? newTime = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: timeInput,
    );
    if (newTime != null) {
      setState(() {
        timeInput = newTime;
  

        });
         }
        }

    ...
    ...
    ...

    //time selector
    ElevatedButton(
       onPressed: _selectTime,
       child: const Text('SELECT TIME'),
       ),
    const SizedBox(height: 5),
    Text(
       'Selected time: ${timeInput.format(context)}',
    ),
```

Here is the code in the card that recalls this information (on the page in which it is called, this card formats the called data from Firestore.

```
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
              child: Text(
                "$dateEvent at $timeHour:$timeMinute",
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 12,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

What is causing the digits to appear as single digits and not double as I can't seem to spot the problem?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Firestore. Number type data just don't render with leading zeros in any normal circumstance.  What you need to do is called "zero padding", and it requires code to convert the number to a string that displays the way you want.

Comment: @DougStevenson it calls and then gets the info from Firestore. However, this did help fix it as I realise the issue was how the cards were formatted. Thank you! +1